# Allowing query strings in RegexRequestMatcher

Tags: java, grails, spring-security

I am attempting to add a RegexRequestMatcher which will look for urls that have a particular url parameter and redirect requests to a custom AuthenticationEntryPoint. I am having difficulty, however, matching url parameters as they seem to be getting removed from the incoming HttpServletRequest. After some significant searching it sounded like spring security intentionally filtered these out of the incoming requests for security reasons.

It appeared that there was a property stripQueryStringFromUrls which overrode this behavior which could be set via a BeanPostProcessor on the DefaultFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource class, however as of 3.1 this property no longer exists (in 3.0.0 it appeared to have moved to FilterChainProxy before disappearing entirely with the next release).

Does spring security still strip out query strings by default or was the disappearance of the configuration property a result of that behavior being removed? If it still does, how do you enabled url parameters as of spring security 3.1?

I am using Spring Security 3.1.3 through the grails spring security plugin (1.2.7).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stripQueryStringFromUrls was indeed removed inbetween the 3.0 and 3.1 releases of spring security web. The entire functionality was taken out and instead the RequestMatcher objects were made to handle request transformation as necessary. This can be verified in the following commit diff of the class DefaultFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource
[commit diff of the class DefaultFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/commit/93438defffe5c339026469afa09dad60b2928a4f#diff-3f6e2075e323cfbfe09ef1d4b10376edR31).

Instead the framework was changed so that using **AntPathRequestMatcher** will result in the query string being ignored whereas using **RegexRequestMatcher** will take it into account (and using a custom RequestMatcher will do whatever you choose to have it do.

As such the above implementation **should have** worked. It turns out the actual issue (which wasn't apparent in the question) was with the url itself which was being used to test spring security. The correct order for a url is

[url base] + [query params] + [page fragment] e.g. localhost/something?param=whatever#/blah

but I was attempting to order it as such

[url base] + [page fragment] + [query params] e.g. localhost/something#/blah?param=whatever

which caused the query params to be lost along with the page fragment. When done in the correct order spring security properly receives and parses the request accordingly.